# Cannot deploy my Xamarin application on my Genymotion AVD

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, genymotion

I'm using `MSVS2015Pro` with `C#/Xamarin/Genymotion`.

I have an already configured `AVD` with `Genymotion`.

I can start it successfully.

Then, while this `AVD` is running, I'm trying to deploy my `Hello World` application on it but I'm getting the following error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.120.101:5555 devices 
1>error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (10048)
1>could not read ok from ADB Server
1>* failed to start daemon *
1>error: cannot connect to daemon
1>List of devices attached
1>adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
1>
1>Selected device is not running.
1>Build FAILED.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks, that worked and fixed the problem